# Meaning of relative tolerance in minimization routine (minpack's hybrd1)

Tags: mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods

I am using a port of minpack's `hybrd1` in [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/group__NonLinearOptimization__Module.html) which uses [Powell's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powell%27s_method) to find solution of f(x)=0; the jacobian is computed numerically, in this case.

The solver accepts `xtol` parameter, relative tolerance, which is by default `sqrt(eps)` for given numerical type (`double` in my case)

In most cases, I get satisfactory solution with residuals vector norm like `1.446575e-9`. Sometimes, though, solution giving norm e.g. 523.543 is accepted, which makes me wonder what the meaning of `xtol` actually is. What is the reference value against which is the current residuals norm compared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out by code inspection eventually, `xtol` is relative to the norm of the initial guess (provided by the user) where the solver starts.